# Invariant Violation: is not usable as a native method argument & PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large in FlatList loading data

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, payload

I got errors while working with FlatList, Material Bottom Tabs and Material Top Tabs. It generates errors which seem like they are related to load performance.
Here is my component:

```
<FlatList
   nativeID="gallery-viewer_food-wallpaper_list"
   style={{
      width: windowDimensions.windowWidth,
      height: '100%',
      overflow: 'scroll',
   }}
   numColumns={numberOfGridColumns}
   key={numberOfGridColumns}
   data={foodWallpapers}
   renderItem={({ item }) => {
      return (
         <TouchableOpacity
            nativeID="gallery-viewer_image-frame"
            style={{
               width: windowDimensions.windowWidth - globalComponentPaddings.galleryPadding * 2,
               height: '100%',
               flex: 1,
               borderRadius: globalBorderRadiuses.bigBorderRadius,
            }}
            onPress={() => {
               route.params.currentSelectedImage = item.token;
               imageSelectionState[(parseInt(item.token) - 1) / 2] += 1;
               console.log(parseInt(item.token));
               console.log(imageSelectionState[parseInt(item.token) - 1]);
            }}
         >
            <Image
               nativeID="gallery-viewer_image-viewer"
               source={item.source}
               resizeMode={'cover'}
               style={{
                  width: windowDimensions.windowWidth - globalComponentPaddings.galleryPadding * 2,
                  height: '100%',
                  flex: 1,
                  borderRadius: globalBorderRadiuses.bigBorderRadius,
                  borderColor: globalColors.black,
                  borderWidth: 3,
               }}
            />
            <View
               nativeID="image_selection-wrapper"
               style={{
                  width: 40,
                  height: 40,
                  position: 'absolute',
                  marginTop: 4,
                  marginRight: 0,
                  marginLeft: '86%', 
                  display: (imageSelectionState[parseInt(item.token) - 1] % 2 === 0) ? 'none' : 'flex',
               }}
            >
               <Image
                  nativeID="image_selection-mark"
                  source={require("../assets/icons/selected_5.png")}
                  style={{
                     width: 40,
                     height: 40,
                     resizeMethod: 'scale',
                     resizeMode: 'cover',
                  }}
               />
            </View>
         </TouchableOpacity>
      );
   }}
   keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

```
Invariant Violation: [109,"RCTImageView",521,{"nativeID":"gallery-viewer_image-viewer","resizeMode":"cover","width":"<<NaN>>","height":"100%","overflow":"hidden","flex":1,"borderRadius":21,"borderColor":-16777216,"borderWidth":3,"shouldNotifyLoadEvents":false,"src":[{"uri":"http://192.168.1.4:19000/assets/assets/gallery/food/food_1.png?platform=android&hash=d553bbd857fa34e93620f07f0ba4aeef?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false"}],"defaultSrc":null,"loadingIndicatorSrc":null}] is not usable as a native method argument
```

and

```
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large 
at readStream (...\node_modules\expo\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:155:17)
```

I did modify the value of limit in `\node_modules\expo\node_modules\raw-body\index.js` But still got the first error. Please help me to resolve the problem. Thanks for any helpful solutions!